# VB.NET LINQ cannot convert result to dictionary

Tags: vb.net, linq, dictionary

I have a list of lists and a string, using each character in the string i need to get all the sublists that contain the specified character and return the result as a dictionary.

Basically I need the result to be like this `("a": [["a","b"], ["a","c"]], "b": [["a","b"],...)`, I tried this:

```
Dim MyLists As New List(Of List(Of String)) '[["a","b"], ["a","c"], ["d","e"], ...]
Dim MyString As String = "axz"

Dim MyDict As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of List(Of String))) = (From s In MyString _
                                                                 From u In MyLists _
                                                                 Where u.Contains(s) _
                                                                 Group s Into g = Group _
                                                                 Select g).ToDictionary( _
                                                                 Function(g) g.Key, _
                                                                 Function(g) g.Value)
```

But I'm getting stuck at the last bit where It should convert to dictionary! Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure you need a dictionary? Is there a reason you can't use a `Lookup`? That way you could avoid the whole Group By step.

Comment: sorry i'm not sure what do you mean by `lookup` but i need it to be in a dictionary like format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `GroupBy`:

```
Dim query = From chr In MyString.Distinct()
            Where MyLists.Any(Function(l) l.Contains(chr.ToString()))
Dim dict As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of List(Of String))) = query.ToDictionary(
    Function(chr) chr.ToString(),
    Function(chr) MyLists.FindAll(Function(l) l.Contains(chr)))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's throwing an error: `TypeInitializationException was unhandled`

Comment: it was throwing the error because i declated `query` and `dict` as `Private Shared`! what's wrong with that? it's working now after changing it to `Dim` thanks

Comment: I'd avoid having these as static/shared fields. Make them instance properties, initialize them in the constructor. It'll be far easier to do some barrier checking, and to debug when it goes wrong. You got the `TypeInitializationException` because you've set `OPTION STRICT` to `Off`. I strongly recommend to set it to `On`, then the code would not even compile because the type of `query` cannot be inferred. It would work if you'd specify the type: `Private Shared query As IEnumerable(Of Char) = ...`.